# Jenkins Orchestrate the set of some job in CI/CD

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline

Dependency is :

When Job A finished it will start Job B and Job C then Job C starts Job D And when Job D and Job B finishes then only We need to start the Job E.

Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join plugin along with build pipeline plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

- **When Job A finished it will start Job B and Job C**: Job B and Job C can be triggered just as Post build step by A
- **Then Job C starts Job D**: Same thing, D triggered as post build step by C.
- **When Job D and Job B finishes then only We need to start the Job E**: than i would: you can trigger E from D or B, or from both of them as build step, and then just use in E the parameter "Block build if certain jobs are running", and block set D and B as condition. This way E will be triggered by D and B but it will wait till the time no one of them is running to start running his task. There are other way but i think that this one is the easiest.

[image]

Let me know if it helps...

Comment: where I can find the block build step , Do i need to install any new plugin 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have one question how does it support the scenario :

Suppose I put Job B as a blocking Jobs in the Job E (Saying Job E will start only one Job B and Job D not running )

So I initiated two runs simultaneously  and run 1 it hugs in Job B 

then, in that case, Run, 2 will never complete although for this run Job Job B and Jb D completed.

Comment: Yep the plugin is the one you send the link.. About the scenario i'm not sure i get it :(

Comment: Please try to explain what you mean better. Btw obviously if you are considering to trigger B/D for more times,consecutively,my solution won't work cause D does not distinguish between different runs, it's just waiting for no D/B instances running.Not really connected to this but in general i suggest you: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin, as it has available that can be used to track the behaviour of the parent jobs like (LAST_TRIGGERED_JOB_NAME, TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER)

Comment: it didn't work for the above scenario , Currently I am working with the join plugin to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) which allow you to do just that. For example, after installing the plugin, in Job A you would have the possibility to *Add build step* which will allow you to trigger another job(s).

Comment: As far i know just the parameterized trigger plugin you can't achieve multiple build conditions, but just the parent job one.

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy I have to disagree with you. Please take a look at: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12480

Comment: Hi Sergiu, as far i'm understanding this is a different requirement, the parameterized trigger plugin allows you to run parallel build, we are all agree about this, but it does not allow (as far i knew) that a triggered build waits for other parallels (or not) builds in order to start... mainly, how you can achieve that job E will run just once D and B finished with the parameterzed plugin?

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy , you are correct and thanks for explaining